# PowerBI - Use an Azure Blob as a Data Source for Dataflow

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-blob-storage

Hopefully someone can help. I have a requirement of creating something like a "bring your own data model" feature/steps so clients can upload their own files, use it in a PowerBI data flow, link it with other sources (databases, services, etc), and create reports from it. The only problem is I'm having problems creating a data flow from an Azure blob file.

1. The files are CSV format
2. I have premium feature
3. I first tested and created an M query in PowerBI Desktop and it works, I can access the data

[image]

4. What I do is I copy my created M query to the Power BI data flow data source in a blank query. The result will is I can preview the data, but if I try to save it, I'm getting this error:

[image]

I tried the steps on this link but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you find out which line is raising up the error, by trying to save with only the first line inside `let`, then with the 2 first lines, then 3 first lines... ?

Comment: I don't see an error in code. Maybe "Accept" can be in quotes due to headers can be anything. 
Did you try the blob connector? like AzureStorage.Blobs